# Browsers and certificate store

Tags: browser, ssl, ssl-certificate

In which certificate stores do browsers look for trusted certificate, when they compare it to the one they receive when connecting to `https` server(windows)?

Answer (score 4):

You need the root CA certificate in the trusted root store that the particular browser uses. Here is a page from a simple Google search that may help: https://help.riseup.net/security/certificates/import/

The browser does *not* need to find the server's certificate here. What needs to be installed in this store is the root CA cert that signed the server's certificate (or certificate chain.)

For example, if the server has a certificate S, and S is signed by "MY-ROOT-CA", then MY-ROOT-CA needs to be installed in the trusted root store.

If the server's certificate S is signed by an intermediate CA "SOME-CA", and SOME-CA is signed by MY-ROOT-CA, then again only MY-ROOT-CA needs to be installed on the browser machine in the trusted root store.

If S is signed by SOME-CA, then SOME-CA may also need to be installed somewhere on the browser machine, but not necessarily in the trusted root store. In this case, the server may be sending both S and SOME-CA, and may even send MY-ROOT-CA. However long this chain of certificates gets, each link in the chain has to be sent by the server, or present on the local machine, but the very last MY-ROOT-CA always has to be installed and this in the special trusted root store.

Comment: The only part about this answer that is NOT true is the requirement the root issuing public certificate must be in the cert store. In fact, it can be *any* certificate in the issuance chain, including the public certificate of the site (S) itself. Once a certificate in the issuance chain is discovered in the trusted root store, trust is established and the searching stops. only revocation can stop trust at that point. For the example of above, S in the trusted root store establishes trust the same was SA (the issuer of S) does if it is in the store.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That depends on the TLS implementation you are using. OpenSSL will not verify the cert unless the root self-signed CA is in the trust store. The presence of a subordinate CA in the trust store is not enough.